# Remove a QListWidgetItem from QListWidget?

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I checked latest documentation, nothing related was found. I place a pointer to a `QListWidgetItem` in my class, and I want to use some function from `QListWidget` to remove this child item.

What I found was only to remove this by ID, `takeItem (i)`.

Is there any better / real way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

> To remove items from the list, use takeItem().

According to the docs, that is the correct method to use.